# Consuming Zend_Rest_Server response with jquery

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax, web-services, zend-framework

Is there is standard way to consume Zend_Rest_Server response with jquery?
I have a simple web service that I need to invoke and process result with ajax,
preferrably JQuery.

I assume I can parse xml response somehow, but that doesn't look like a mature solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has the [$.ajax()](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.ajax#options) command for making ajax calls. One of the dataType options is xml to indicate that the response will be in xml. jQuery also supports [XPath style selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/DOM/Traversing/Selectors) too, for easily working with xml.

Is there anything else that you need to know?

Comment: The service returns a simple response, data or error message, so I think XPath will suffice. Thinking ahead, if my ajax app would have to consume more services, I'd write some basic layer using XPAth. Thanks!